# How can I delete Other files in storage?

Tags: lumia, lumia-520, storage

I received 730mb of data via Bluetooth. But I can't view it because the format isn't supported. So it is stored as Other. How can I delete it?

Comment: What was this data?

Comment: Download any file manager app from the windows phone store, to view those unsupported file formats. E.g ( Files, Aerize Explorer)

Answer (score 2):

The process of deleting files categorized as Other really varies depending on what type the files are. You could plug your phone into your PC and try to delete files that way, or download the [Files](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/files/762e837f-461d-4847-8399-3526f54fc25e) app; if you're sure it's stored in Other (AFAIK there's no way to see what's actually in other). But there isn't a definite answer for how to delete them.